# Accessing Individual SSE Payloads in Response using Java

Tags: java, server-sent-events

We are currently using Apache `HttpClient` (5) to send a `POST` request to a server. The response is sent back to us using server side events (SSE) with multiple payloads using the standard format:

```
data: {...}
```

Currently we have code like this which sends the request and receives the response:

```java
// Set the socket timeout
final ConnectionConfig connConfig = ConnectionConfig.custom()
                    .setSocketTimeout(socketTimeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                    .build();

// Custom config
final BasicHttpClientConnectionManager cm = new BasicHttpClientConnectionManager();
            cm.setConnectionConfig(connConfig);

// Build the client
try (final CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().setConnectionManager(cm).build()) {

      // Execute the request
      return client.execute(request.getRequest(),

              // Get and process the response          
              response -> HttpResponse.builder()
                              .withCode(response.getCode())
                              .withContent(EntityUtils.toByteArray(response.getEntity()))
                              .build()
                );

      }
```

This all works great except I need to access the individual incoming response payloads (`data {...}`) in the response as they arrive instead of waiting for them all to finish before being able to access the response.

If this isn't possible using Apache I am open to other options providing they can send a normal HTTP(S) `POST`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I couldn't get it to work with the `Apache Client` but I did find this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qwzNzlI66ro) that showed how to do it using the native `HttpClient`.

```java
// Create the client
final HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();

// Make the request 
final HttpResponse<Stream<String>> response = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofLines());

// Status code check
if (response.statusCode() != 200) ...;

// This will consume individual events as they arrive
response.body().forEach(System.out::println);
```